# In puppeteer page.evaluate can't find text

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to retrieve  "document.querySelector(".navigator__results").childNodes[0]" to my variable result

```
const result = await page.evaluate( async () => {
    const a = await document.querySelector(".navigator__results").childNodes[0];
    console.log(a);
    return a
});
console.log(result);
```

The console.log(a) on the browser works.
But the console.log(result) doesn't

Any ideas how to tackle this issue ?

Have tried to delay it as shown bellow, but no success:

```
     await page.waitFor(10000);
     const result = await page.evaluate( async () => {
        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }
        await sleep(8000);
        console.log(document.querySelector(".navigator__results").childNodes[0]);
        const a = await document.querySelector(".navigator__results").childNodes[0];
        console.log(a);
        return a;

     });
     console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector(".navigator__results").childNodes[0]` returns HTML element. You can log it in the browser console, but you cannot retrieve it via `page.evaluate()`: [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can transfer only serializable data (roughly speaking — the data JSON can handle), and HTML element can't be serialized, so `undefined` is returned.

Also, you don't need `await` for `document.querySelector()` :)